# FTP Server on an Azure virtual machine

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, azure, ftp

I have an azure virtual machine Windows Server 2012 RC, and I would like to share a large folder to copy to my computer.

I tried to install the FTP service, but does not understand what IP address to put when I add a FTP site.

So, I installed and launched the Filezilla Server, it says:

```
FileZilla Server 0.9.60 beta
Copyright 2001-2016 by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org)
https://filezilla-project.org/
Connecting to server localhost:14147...
Connected, waiting for authentication
Logged on


You appear to be behind a NAT router. 
Please configure the passive mode settings and forward a range of ports in your router.

Warning: FTP over TLS is not enabled, users cannot securely log in.
```

I just want to copy my large folder and close the FTP, because I don't see another way to copy that folder on my local disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [guide](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_azure_ftps_server) outlines how you can do this by installing secure FTP using IIS.

You'll need to install the FTP Server Role Service in Windows. You then need to tell the FTP server its external IP address, to allow passive mode connections.

Open IIS Manager, open FTP > FTP Firewall Support. Specify your server’s external IP address. Change the Data Channel Port Range to 5000-5100. Restart the FTP Service.

Add inbound rules to the NSG linked to the VM for FTP and ports 5000-5100

Comment: Thanks a lot in my case as I need it urgently, I used a Azure blob storage to upload it (very fast upload for my 42 GB archive, because server is already on Azure), and then download it via the Azure Storage Explorer client... However thanks a lot for instructions of how to setup the FTP, it may be useful for other people in cases like the mine!